# ASP Creating Text File ObjFileSys.CreateTextFile

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, filesystemobject

I am trying to create a textfile in a temp directory...

I don't understand what I am doing wrong...

My Error is:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a004c'
Path not found
/racklabels/desktop/printLabel.asp, line 128
```

There is a temp directory on my server I am running this from...

```
strFileNameQAD = "C:\temp\" & strFileNameRBB

'Create the files, write to them & close them.
If bBackFlush = True Then
    Set filQAD = objFileSys.CreateTextFile(strFileNameQAD)
    filQAD.WriteLine ("H::" & strPart & strLocation & strSite & strQty & strSerial & strRef & strUserID & strAccount & strSubAccount & strCostCenter & strEffDate & strYes)
    filQAD.WriteLine ("D::" & strFromLocation & strNo & strUserID)
    filQAD.Close
    Set filQAD = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Interesting a [tag:asp-classic] question that has been tagged [tag:asp.net] makes a change. So you know for future reference [tag:asp-classic] and [tag:asp.net] are not the same thing. Your question is about [tag:asp-classic].

Comment: Which line is `line 128` in your code snippet?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was not sure...    Line 128 is:           Set filQAD = objFileSys.CreateTextFile(strFileNameQAD)

Comment: @Lankymart - had to upvote that comment!  ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FileSystemObject is complaining about the path contained in the `strFileNameQAD`, try placing a `Response.Write strFileNameQAD : Response.Flush` before the offending line to see what `strFileNameQAD` outputs as.

> **Note:** `Response.Flush` causes the server to write the response headers and buffer, so even if your script errors the output will be shown first.

```vb
strFileNameQAD = "C:\temp\" & strFileNameRBB

'Create the files, write to them & close them.
If bBackFlush = True Then
    'Output strFileNameQAD variable to check content
    Response.Write strFileNameQAD : Response.Flush
    Set filQAD = objFileSys.CreateTextFile(strFileNameQAD)
    filQAD.WriteLine ("H::" & strPart & strLocation & strSite & strQty & strSerial & strRef & strUserID & strAccount & strSubAccount & strCostCenter & strEffDate & strYes)
    filQAD.WriteLine ("D::" & strFromLocation & strNo & strUserID)
    filQAD.Close
    Set filQAD = Nothing
End If
```

Does the `strFileNameQAD` variable contain the expected path? My guess would be that `strFileNameRBB` is empty so the `FileSystemObject` sees `C:\temp\` but no file to create, hence the error.

Comment: Awesome! You are correct, it was empty! Thank you for figuring this out, I spent alot of time thinking my syntax was incorrect... Thanks again for the clarification earlier as well!

Comment: @KyleRickaby No problem, sometimes the error is the give away. For example if it had been a syntax error I doubt it would have told you `Path not found`, it would have been more a long the lines of `Invalid Type Specified` or `Incorrect Syntax`. Glad it's sorted.